# Код вызовов функций создаётся без "трамплина"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ассемблер, gcc, компиляция

Компилирую прогу на асме под 32-битный Linux на 64-битной системе Ubuntu. Сначала код не компилися, выдавал ошибку:

```
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
cannot find -lgcc
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Установил **gcc-multilib** - всё заработало, вот только код стал создаваться без трамплинов: вызов **call XXX** ведёт непосредственно на функцию, а не на **jmp**, который прыгает на функцию (аналогично тому, как в Windows происходит вызов dll-функции).

Мне же надо позарез, чтобы **call** вёл к трамплину. Как это сделать? Может, ключи какие-то проставить нужно особые для **gcc** или ещё что-то?

Comment: Не понял, в чём польза от лишнего jmp...

Comment: В том, что можно, например, подменить функцию (модифицировать её должным образом).

Comment: В смысле, я понимаю, как это можно использовать, но не понимаю, почему компилятору должно захотеться так делать. Кстати, можно jmp и внутрь функции засунуть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что, насколько я понимаю, в норме так и происходит. Мне один чел скинул прогу, в которой именно так. А у него нет проблем с компиляцией без всяких там **gcc-multilib**. Ну и есть мануалы, где об этом написано (что должен быть трамплин). Возможно, проблема возникла в результате установки **gcc-multilib**. А может, и нет – я не знаю. Ну а чтобы засунуть **jmp** внутрь функции нужно иметь права на запись в исполняемый код.

Comment: Я имел в виду при компиляции добавить промежуточную функцию, которая ассемблерной вставкой делает jmp на нужную и инлайнится в место своего вызова. И стоп. А как ты без прав на запись в исполняемый код собрался адрес jmp'а подменять?

Comment: `-m32` (gcc), `--32` (gas) наверное спасёт ситуацию.

Comment: @0andriy, причём тут это? Эти опции стоят...

Comment: @Qwertiy, **call** делается на инструкцю **jmp dword ptr [func_addr]** (условно говоря). Т.е. по адресу **func_addr** (в переменной func_addr) содержиться адрес функции. Эту переменную и меняем... Идею твою не понял с jmp и промежуточной функцией. Нужно подменить ВСЕ вывозы (откуда бы одни не делались в программе). Даже если вызов зашит в какой-то библиотеке или obj'е.

Comment: _"Т.е. по адресу func_addr (в переменной func_addr) содержиться адрес функции. Эту переменную и меняем..."_ - что-то я сомневаюсь, что тут переменная. Скорее, сам адрес. Или нет?

Comment: Нет. Адрес берётся именно из памяти. Вот так это выглядит внешне (hiew): http://i7.5cm.ru/i/7X7r.png . А вот так, когда нажимаем F3 (редактировать): http://i7.5cm.ru/i/WXVJ.png . Это под Windows. В Linux та же система...

Comment: Это для @Qwertiy :)

Comment: А вы можете показать минимальный отрывок исходного кода и результат дизассемблера бинарника того же кусочка?

Comment: @0andriy, исходного кода чего? Вот то, что на картинках - это **invoke ExitProcess, NULL** :)